# How to execute one stored procedure that updates two tables Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

Procedure compiled with no errors to "Insert Into" two tables. How do I execute this? What is the right syntax to send the data for both tables into database? Using Oracle database.

Thanks.

Comment: Without seeing your procedure it's a bit difficult to provide advice. Please edit your question and include the source code of your procedure. Thanks.

Comment: Without knowing what your client is it's even more difficult to provide advice. Please edit your question and include the missing info. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To execute a stored procedure in oracle use execute. 
e.g

```
execute procedure()
```

change procedure to whatever you have called your procedure